# Ext4 "Block bitmap differences" on new USB3 drives

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, ext4

I just bought two new USB3 drives, 2.1TB capacity and they came formatted to ExFAT.  Normally I'd reformat to NTFS because NTFS works on Microsoft and Linux devices but recent difficulty with drive recovery made me rethink that.  I tried formatting them to Ext4 with `gnome-disks` and they wouldn't mount, saying they were the "wrong filesystem". I tried `mke2fs -t ext4 -O ^has_journal /dev/sdg1` and now they mount.  Feeling suspicious of their integrity, I ran `fsck.ext4 -Dfy -C 0 /dev/sdg1` (the drives were unmounted) on them which found a couple hundred lines of Block bitmap differences.  **fsck.ext4** said it had fixed them but when I ran it again, precisely the same differences showed up.

The same differences show up on both of the new drives, but I tried running the same commands on two other drives I have (a 4GB USB2 and a 16GB USB3) and no such errors come up.

I can't find anything that will tell me how concerning these errors are.  Do I return the drives, is it fixable, or is it a minor detail?
This is what I got from **fsck.ext4**:

> Block bitmap differences:  -(4202528--4227071) -(4726816--4751359)
>   -(5251104--5275647) -(5775392--5799935) -(6299680--6324223) -(6823968--6848511) -(7348256--7372799) -(7872544--7897087) -(8396832--8421375) -(8921120--8945663) -(9445408--9469951) -(9969696--9994239) -(10493984--10518527) -(11018272--11042815) -(11542560--11567103) -(12066848--12091391) -(12591136--12615679) -(13115424--13139967) -(13639712--13664255) -(14164000--14188543) -(14688288--14712831) -(15212576--15237119) -(15736864--15761407) -(16261152--16285695) -(16785440--16809983) -(17309728--17334271) -(17834016--17858559) -(18358304--18382847) -(18882592--18907135) -(19406880--19431423) -(19931168--19955711) -(20455456--20479999) -(20979744--21004287) -(21504032--21528575) -(22028320--22052863) -(22552608--22577151) -(23076896--23101439) -(23601184--23625727) -(24125472--24150015) -(24649760--24674303) -(25174048--25198591) -(25698336--25722879) -(26222624--26247167) -(26746912--26771455) -(27271200--27295743) -(27795488--27820031) -(28319776--28344319) -(28844064--28868607) -(29368352--29392895) -(29892640--29917183) -(30416928--30441471) -(30941216--30965759) -(31465504--31490047) -(31989792--32014335) -(32514080--32538623) -(33038368--33062911) -(33562656--33587199) -(34086944--34111487) -(34611232--34635775) -(35135520--35160063) -(35659808--35684351) -(36184096--36208639) -(36708384--36732927) -(37232672--37257215) -(37756960--37781503) -(38281248--38305791) -(38805536--38830079) -(39329824--39354367) -(39854112--39878655) -(40378400--40402943) -(40902688--40927231) -(41426976--41451519) -(41951264--41975807) -(42475552--42500095) -(42999840--43024383) -(43524128--43548671) -(44048416--44072959) -(44572704--44597247) -(45096992--45121535) -(45621280--45645823) -(46145568--46170111) -(46669856--46694399) -(47194144--47218687) -(47718432--47742975) -(48242720--48267263) -(48767008--48791551) -(49291296--49315839) -(49815584--49840127) -(50339872--50364415) -(50864160--50888703) -(51388448--51412991) -(51912736--51937279) -(52437024--52461567) -(52961312--52985855) -(53485600--53510143) -(54009888--54034431) -(54534176--54558719) -(55058464--55083007) -(55582752--55607295) -(56107040--56131583) -(56631328--56655871) -(57155616--57180159) -(57679904--57704447) -(58204192--58228735) -(58728480--58753023) -(59252768--59277311) -(59777056--59801599) -(60301344--60325887) -(60825632--60850175) -(61349920--61374463) -(61874208--61898751) -(62398496--62423039) -(62922784--62947327) -(63447072--63471615) -(63971360--63995903) -(64495648--64520191) -(65019936--65044479) -(65544224--65568767) -(66068512--66093055) -(66592800--66617343) -(67117088--67141631) -(67641376--67665919) -(68165664--68190207) -(68689952--68714495) -(69214240--69238783) -(69738528--69763071) -(70262816--70287359) -(70787104--70811647) -(71311392--71335935) -(71835680--71860223) -(72359968--72384511) -(72884256--72908799) -(73408544--73433087) -(73932832--73957375) -(74457120--74481663) -(74981408--75005951) -(75505696--75530239) -(76029984--76054527) -(76554272--76578815) -(77078560--77103103) -(77602848--77627391) -(78127136--78151679) -(78651424--78675967) -(79175712--79200255) -(79700000--79724543) -(80224288--80248831) -(80748576--80773119) -(81272864--81297407) -(81797152--81821695) -(82321440--82345983) -(82845728--82870271) -(83370016--83394559) -(83894304--83918847) -(84418592--84443135) -(84942880--84967423) -(85467168--85491711) -(85991456--86015999) -(86515744--86540287) -(87040032--87064575) -(87564320--87588863) -(88088608--88113151) -(88612896--88637439) -(89137184--89161727) -(89661472--89686015) -(90185760--90210303) -(90710048--90734591) -(91234336--91258879) -(91758624--91783167) -(92282912--92307455) -(92807200--92831743) -(93331488--93356031) -(93855776--93880319) -(94380064--94404607) -(94904352--94928895) -(95428640--95453183) -(95952928--95977471) -(96477216--96501759) -(97001504--97026047) -(97525792--97550335) -(98050080--98074623) -(98574368--98598911) -(99098656--99123199) -(99622944--99647487) -(100147232--100171775) -(100671520--100696063) -(101195808--101220351) -(101720096--101744639) -(102244384--102268927) -(102768672--102793215) -(103292960--103317503) -(103817248--103841791) -(104341536--104366079) -(104865824--104890367) -(105390112--105414655) -(105914400--105938943) -(106438688--106463231) -(106962976--106987519) -(107487264--107511807) -(108011552--108036095) -(108535840--108560383) -(109060128--109084671) -(109584416--109608959) -(110108704--110133247) -(110632992--110657535) -(111157280--111181823) -(111681568--111706111) -(112205856--112230399) -(112730144--112754687) -(113254432--113278975) -(113778720--113803263) -(114303008--114327551) -(114827296--114851839) -(115351584--115376127) -(115875872--115900415) -(116400160--116424703) -(116924448--116948991) -(117448736--117473279) -(117973024--117997567) -(118497312--118521855) -(119021600--119046143) -(119545888--119570431) -(120070176--120094719) -(120594464--120619007) -(121118752--121143295) -(121643040--121667583) -(122167328--122191871) -(122691616--122716159) -(123215904--123240447) -(123740192--123764735) -(124264480--124289023) -(124788768--124813311) -(125313056--125337599) -(125837344--125861887) -(126361632--126386175) -(126885920--126910463) -(127410208--127434751) -(127934496--127959039) -(128458784--128483327) -(128983072--129007615) -(129507360--129531903) -(130031648--130056191) -(130555936--130580479) -(131080224--131104767) -(131604512--131629055) -(132128800--132153343) -(132653088--132677631) -(133177376--133201919) -(133701664--133726207) -(134225952--134250495) -(134750240--134774783) -(135274528--135299071) -(135798816--135823359) -(136323104--136347647) -(136847392--136871935) -(137371680--137396223) -(137895968--137920511) -(138420256--138444799) -(138944544--138969087) -(139468832--139493375) -(139993120--140017663) -(140517408--140541951) -(141041696--141066239) -(141565984--141590527) -(142090272--142114815) -(142614560--142639103) -(143138848--143163391) -(143663136--143687679) -(144187424--144211967) -(144711712--144736255) -(145236000--145260543) -(145760288--145784831) -(146284576--146309119) -(146808864--146833407) -(147333152--147357695) -(147857440--147881983) -(148381728--148406271) -(148906016--148930559) -(149430304--149454847) -(149954592--149979135) -(150478880--150503423) -(151003168--151027711) -(151527456--151551999) -(152051744--152076287) -(152576032--152600575) -(153100320--153124863) -(153624608--153649151) -(154148896--154173439) -(154673184--154697727) -(155197472--155222015) -(155721760--155746303) -(156246048--156270591) -(156770336--156794879) -(157294624--157319167) -(157818912--157843455) -(158343200--158367743) -(158867488--158892031) -(159391776--159416319) -(159916064--159940607) -(160440352--160464895) -(160964640--160989183) -(161488928--161513471) -(162013216--162037759) -(162537504--162562047) -(163061792--163086335) -(163586080--163610623) -(164110368--164134911) -(164634656--164659199) -(165158944--165183487) -(165683232--165707775) -(166207520--166232063) -(166731808--166756351) -(167256096--167280639) -(167780384--167804927) -(168304672--168329215) -(168828960--168853503) -(169353248--169377791) -(169877536--169902079) -(170401824--170426367) -(170926112--170950655) -(171450400--171474943) -(171974688--171999231) -(172498976--172523519) -(173023264--173047807) -(173547552--173572095) -(174071840--174096383) -(174596128--174620671) -(175120416--175144959) -(175644704--175669247) -(176168992--176193535) -(176693280--176717823) -(177217568--177242111) -(177741856--177766399) -(178266144--178290687) -(178790432--178814975) -(179314720--179339263) -(179839008--179863551) -(180363296--180387839) -(180887584--180912127) -(181411872--181436415) -(181936160--181960703) -(182460448--182484991) -(182984736--183009279) -(183509024--183533567) -(184033312--184057855) -(184557600--184582143) -(185081888--185106431) -(185606176--185630719) -(186130464--186155007) -(186654752--186679295) -(187179040--187203583) -(187703328--187727871) -(188227616--188252159) -(188751904--188776447) -(189276192--189300735) -(189800480--189825023) -(190324768--190349311) -(190849056--190873599) -(191373344--191397887) -(191897632--191922175) -(192421920--192446463) -(192946208--192970751) -(193470496--193495039) -(193994784--194019327) -(194519072--194543615) -(195043360--195067903) -(195567648--195592191) -(196091936--196116479) -(196616224--196640767) -(197140512--197165055) -(197664800--197689343) -(198189088--198213631) -(198713376--198737919) -(199237664--199262207) -(199761952--199786495) -(200286240--200310783) -(200810528--200835071) -(201334816--201359359) -(201859104--201883647) -(202383392--202407935) -(202907680--202932223) -(203431968--203456511) -(203956256--203980799) -(204480544--204505087) -(205004832--205029375) -(205529120--205553663) -(206053408--206077951) -(206577696--206602239) -(207101984--207126527) -(207626272--207650815) -(208150560--208175103) -(208674848--208699391) -(209199136--209223679) -(209723424--209747967) -(210247712--210272255) -(210772000--210796543) -(211296288--211320831) -(211820576--211845119) -(212344864--212369407) -(212869152--212893695) -(213393440--213417983) -(213917728--213942271) -(214442016--214466559) -(214966304--214990847) -(215490592--215515135) -(216014880--216039423) -(216539168--216563711) -(217063456--217087999) -(217587744--217612287) -(218112032--218136575) -(218636320--218660863) -(219160608--219185151) -(219684896--219709439) -(220209184--220233727) -(220733472--220758015) -(221257760--221282303) -(221782048--221806591) -(222306336--222330879) -(222830624--222855167) -(223354912--223379455) -(223879200--223903743) -(224403488--224428031) -(224927776--224952319) -(225452064--225476607) -(225976352--226000895) -(226500640--226525183) -(227024928--227049471) -(227549216--227573759) -(228073504--228098047) -(228597792--228622335) -(229122080--229146623) -(229646368--229670911) -(230170656--230195199) -(230694944--230719487) -(231219232--231243775) -(231743520--231768063) -(232267808--232292351) -(232792096--232816639) -(233316384--233340927) -(233840672--233865215) -(234364960--234389503) -(234889248--234913791) -(235413536--235438079) -(235937824--235962367) -(236462112--236486655) -(236986400--237010943) -(237510688--237535231) -(238034976--238059519) -(238559264--238583807) -(239083552--239108095) -(239607840--239632383) -(240132128--240156671) -(240656416--240680959) -(241180704--241205247) -(241704992--241729535) -(242229280--242253823) -(242753568--242778111) -(243277856--243302399) -(243802144--243826687) -(244326432--244350975) -(244850720--244875263) -(245375008--245399551) -(245899296--245923839) -(246423584--246448127) -(246947872--246972415) -(247472160--247496703) -(247996448--248020991) -(248520736--248545279) -(249045024--249069567) -(249569312--249593855) -(250093600--250118143) -(250617888--250642431) -(251142176--251166719) -(251666464--251691007) -(252190752--252215295) -(252715040--252739583) -(253239328--253263871) -(253763616--253788159) -(254287904--254312447) -(254812192--254836735) -(255336480--255361023) -(255860768--255885311) -(256385056--256409599) -(256909344--256933887) -(257433632--257458175) -(257957920--257982463) -(258482208--258506751) -(259006496--259031039) -(259530784--259555327) -(260055072--260079615) -(260579360--260603903) -(261103648--261128191) -(261627936--261652479) -(262152224--262176767) -(262676512--262701055) -(263200800--263225343) -(263725088--263749631) -(264249376--264273919) -(264773664--264798207) -(265297952--265322495) -(265822240--265846783) -(266346528--266371071) -(266870816--266895359) -(267395104--267419647) -(267919392--267943935) -(268443680--268468223) -(268967968--268992511) -(269492256--269516799) -(270016544--270041087) -(270540832--270565375) -(271065120--271089663) -(271589408--271613951) -(272113696--272138239) -(272637984--272662527) -(273162272--273186815) -(273686560--273711103) -(274210848--274235391) -(274735136--274759679) -(275259424--275283967) -(275783712--275808255) -(276308000--276332543) -(276832288--276856831) -(277356576--277381119) -(277880864--277905407) -(278405152--278429695) -(278929440--278953983) -(279453728--279478271) -(279978016--280002559) -(280502304--280526847) -(281026592--281051135) -(281550880--281575423) -(282075168--282099711) -(282599456--282623999) -(283123744--283148287) -(283648032--283672575) -(284172320--284196863) -(284696608--284721151) -(285220896--285245439) -(285745184--285769727) -(286269472--286294015) -(286793760--286818303) -(287318048--287342591) -(287842336--287866879) -(288366624--288391167) -(288890912--288915455) -(289415200--289439743) -(289939488--289964031) -(290463776--290488319) -(290988064--291012607) -(291512352--291536895) -(292036640--292061183) -(292560928--292585471) -(293085216--293109759) -(293609504--293634047) -(294133792--294158335) -(294658080--294682623) -(295182368--295206911) -(295706656--295731199) -(296230944--296255487) -(296755232--296779775) -(297279520--297304063) -(297803808--297828351) -(298328096--298352639) -(298852384--298876927) -(299376672--299401215) -(299900960--299925503) -(300425248--300449791) -(300949536--300974079) -(301473824--301498367) -(301998112--302022655) -(302522400--302546943) -(303046688--303071231) -(303570976--303595519) -(304095264--304119807) -(304619552--304644095) -(305143840--305168383) -(305668128--305692671) -(306192416--306216959) -(306716704--306741247) -(307240992--307265535) -(307765280--307789823) -(308289568--308314111) -(308813856--308838399) -(309338144--309362687) -(309862432--309886975) -(310386720--310411263) -(310911008--310935551) -(311435296--311459839) -(311959584--311984127) -(312483872--312508415) -(313008160--313032703) -(313532448--313556991) -(314056736--314081279) -(314581024--314605567) -(315105312--315129855) -(315629600--315654143) -(316153888--316178431) -(316678176--316702719) -(317202464--317227007) -(317726752--317751295) -(318251040--318275583) -(318775328--318799871) -(319299616--319324159) -(319823904--319848447) -(320348192--320372735) -(320872480--320897023) -(321396768--321421311) -(321921056--321945599) -(322445344--322469887) -(322969632--322994175) -(323493920--323518463) -(324018208--324042751) -(324542496--324567039) -(325066784--325091327) -(325591072--325615615) -(326115360--326139903) -(326639648--326664191) -(327163936--327188479) -(327688224--327712767) -(328212512--328237055) -(328736800--328761343) -(329261088--329285631) -(329785376--329809919) -(330309664--330334207) -(330833952--330858495) -(331358240--331382783) -(331882528--331907071) -(332406816--332431359) -(332931104--332955647) -(333455392--333479935) -(333979680--334004223) -(334503968--334528511) -(335028256--335052799) -(335552544--335577087) -(336076832--336101375) -(336601120--336625663) -(337125408--337149951) -(337649696--337674239) -(338173984--338198527) -(338698272--338722815) -(339222560--339247103) -(339746848--339771391) -(340271136--340295679) -(340795424--340819967) -(341319712--341344255) -(341844000--341868543) -(342368288--342392831) -(342892576--342917119) -(343416864--343441407) -(343941152--343965695) -(344465440--344489983) -(344989728--345014271) -(345514016--345538559) -(346038304--346062847) -(346562592--346587135) -(347086880--347111423) -(347611168--347635711) -(348135456--348159999) -(348659744--348684287) -(349184032--349208575) -(349708320--349732863) -(350232608--350257151) -(350756896--350781439) -(351281184--351305727) -(351805472--351830015) -(352329760--352354303) -(352854048--352878591) -(353378336--353402879) -(353902624--353927167) -(354426912--354451455) -(354951200--354975743) -(355475488--355500031) -(355999776--356024319) -(356524064--356548607) -(357048352--357072895) -(357572640--357597183) -(358096928--358121471) -(358621216--358645759) -(359145504--359170047) -(359669792--359694335) -(360194080--360218623) -(360718368--360742911) -(361242656--361267199) -(361766944--361791487) -(362291232--362315775) -(362815520--362840063) -(363339808--363364351) -(363864096--363888639) -(364388384--364412927) -(364912672--364937215) -(365436960--365461503) -(365961248--365985791) -(366485536--366510079) -(367009824--367034367) -(367534112--367558655) -(368058400--368082943) -(368582688--368607231) -(369106976--369131519) -(369631264--369655807) -(370155552--370180095) -(370679840--370704383) -(371204128--371228671) -(371728416--371752959) -(372252704--372277247) -(372776992--372801535) -(373301280--373325823) -(373825568--373850111) -(374349856--374374399) -(374874144--374898687) -(375398432--375422975) -(375922720--375947263) -(376447008--376471551) -(376971296--376995839) -(377495584--377520127) -(378019872--378044415) -(378544160--378568703) -(379068448--379092991) -(379592736--379617279) -(380117024--380141567) -(380641312--380665855) -(381165600--381190143) -(381689888--381714431) -(382214176--382238719) -(382738464--382763007) -(383262752--383287295) -(383787040--383811583) -(384311328--384335871) -(384835616--384860159) -(385359904--385384447) -(385884192--385908735) -(386408480--386433023) -(386932768--386957311) -(387457056--387481599) -(387981344--388005887) -(388505632--388530175) -(389029920--389054463) -(389554208--389578751) -(390078496--390103039) -(390602784--390627327) -(391127072--391151615) -(391651360--391675903) -(392175648--392200191) -(392699936--392724479) -(393224224--393248767) -(393748512--393773055) -(394272800--394297343) -(394797088--394821631) -(395321376--395345919) -(395845664--395870207) -(396369952--396394495) -(396894240--396918783) -(397418528--397443071) -(397942816--397967359) -(398467104--398491647) -(398991392--399015935) -(399515680--399540223) -(400039968--400064511) -(400564256--400588799) -(401088544--401113087) -(401612832--401637375) -(402137120--402161663) -(402661408--402685951) -(403185696--403210239) -(403709984--403734527) -(404234272--404258815) -(404758560--404783103) -(405282848--405307391) -(405807136--405831679) -(406331424--406355967) -(406855712--406880255) -(407380000--407404543) -(407904288--407928831) -(408428576--408453119) -(408952864--408977407) -(409477152--409501695) -(410001440--410025983) -(410525728--410550271) -(411050016--411074559) -(411574304--411598847) -(412098592--412123135) -(412622880--412647423) -(413147168--413171711) -(413671456--413695999) -(414195744--414220287) -(414720032--414744575) -(415244320--415268863) -(415768608--415793151) -(416292896--416317439) -(416817184--416841727) -(417341472--417366015) -(417865760--417890303) -(418390048--418414591) -(418914336--418938879) -(419438624--419463167) -(419962912--419987455) -(420487200--420511743) -(421011488--421036031) -(421535776--421560319) -(422060064--422084607) -(422584352--422608895) -(423108640--423133183) -(423632928--423657471) -(424157216--424181759) -(424681504--424706047) -(425205792--425230335) -(425730080--425754623) -(426254368--426278911) -(426778656--426803199) -(427302944--427327487) -(427827232--427851775) -(428351520--428376063) -(428875808--428900351) -(429400096--429424639) -(429924384--429948927) -(430448672--430473215) -(430972960--430997503) -(431497248--431521791) -(432021536--432046079) -(432545824--432570367) -(433070112--433094655) -(433594400--433618943) -(434118688--434143231) -(434642976--434667519) -(435167264--435191807) -(435691552--435716095) -(436215840--436240383) -(436740128--436764671) -(437264416--437288959) -(437788704--437813247) -(438312992--438337535) -(438837280--438861823) -(439361568--439386111) -(439885856--439910399) -(440410144--440434687) -(440934432--440958975) -(441458720--441483263) -(441983008--442007551) -(442507296--442531839) -(443031584--443056127) -(443555872--443580415) -(444080160--444104703) -(444604448--444628991) -(445128736--445153279) -(445653024--445677567) -(446177312--446201855) -(446701600--446726143) -(447225888--447250431) -(447750176--447774719) -(448274464--448299007) -(448798752--448823295) -(449323040--449347583) -(449847328--449871871) -(450371616--450396159) -(450895904--450920447) -(451420192--451444735) -(451944480--451969023) -(452468768--452493311) -(452993056--453017599) -(453517344--453541887) -(454041632--454066175) -(454565920--454590463) -(455090208--455114751) -(455614496--455639039) -(456138784--456163327) -(456663072--456687615) -(457187360--457211903) -(457711648--457736191) -(458235936--458260479) -(458760224--458784767) -(459284512--459309055) -(459808800--459833343) -(460333088--460357631) -(460857376--460881919) -(461381664--461406207) -(461905952--461930495) -(462430240--462454783) -(462954528--462979071) -(463478816--463503359) -(464003104--464027647) -(464527392--464551935) -(465051680--465076223) -(465575968--465600511) -(466100256--466124799) -(466624544--466649087) -(467148832--467173375) -(467673120--467697663) -(468197408--468221951) -(468721696--468746239) -(469245984--469270527) -(469770272--469794815) -(470294560--470319103) -(470818848--470843391) -(471343136--471367679) -(471867424--471891967) -(472391712--472416255) -(472916000--472940543) -(473440288--473464831) -(473964576--473989119) -(474488864--474513407) -(475013152--475037695) -(475537440--475561983) -(476061728--476086271) -(476586016--476610559) -(477110304--477134847) -(477634592--477659135) -(478158880--478183423) -(478683168--478707711) -(479207456--479231999) -(479731744--479756287) -(480256032--480280575) -(480780320--480804863) -(481304608--481329151) -(481828896--481853439) -(482353184--482377727) -(482877472--482902015) -(483401760--483426303) -(483926048--483950591) -(484450336--484474879) -(484974624--484999167) -(485498912--485523455) -(486023200--486047743) -(486547488--486572031) -(487071776--487096319) -(487596064--487620607) -(488120352--488144895) -(488644640--488669183) -(489168928--489193471) -(489693216--489717759) -(490217504--490242047) -(490741792--490766335) -(491266080--491290623) -(491790368--491814911) -(492314656--492339199) -(492838944--492863487) -(493363232--493387775) -(493887520--493912063) -(494411808--494436351) -(494936096--494960639) -(495460384--495484927) -(495984672--496009215) -(496508960--496533503) -(497033248--497057791) -(497557536--497582079) -(498081824--498106367) -(498606112--498630655) -(499130400--499154943) -(499654688--499679231) -(500178976--500203519) -(500703264--500727807) -(501227552--501252095) -(501751840--501776383) -(502276128--502300671) -(502800416--502824959) -(503324704--503349247) -(503848992--503873535) -(504373280--504397823) -(504897568--504922111) -(505421856--505446399) -(505946144--505970687) -(506470432--506494975) -(506994720--507019263) -(507519008--507543551) -(508043296--508067839) -(508567584--508592127) -(509091872--509116415) -(509616160--509640703) -(510140448--510164991) -(510664736--510689279) -(511189024--511213567) -(511709714--511737855) -(511967232--511999743) Fix? yes
>
> /dev/sdg1: |=====================================================   |
>   95.1%    /dev/sdg1: |========================================================| 100.0%
>
> /dev/sdg1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED ***** /dev/sdg1:
>   11/128000000 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 8050731/511999744 blocks

Comment: Where did you buy these USB drives, and what brand were they? I suspect they may be fake.

Comment: @duskwuff I admit the source is not entirely reliable. What do you mean by "fake"?  They do store files and I can read them.

Comment: You got scammed, that's not a real 2TB drive. The only 2tb USB drive I know it's from Kingston but it costs £1,257.76 and you're better with a Samsung T5 2Tb drive which is half the price and probably faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I suspect you have been taken in by a common scam.

Cheap USB drives with unusually large sizes (like 2 TB) are almost always fake. The drive actually has a much smaller amount of storage present, often as little as a few gigabytes; the controller on the drive has been programmed to show a larger size, and to remap writes to nonexistent parts of the drive to other parts of flash memory, or to discard those writes altogether. The corruption you are observing is a clear sign that this is the case -- writes to one part of the filesystem on the drive are corrupting other parts of the filesystem.

There are some tools available to detect the exact nature of these fake drives, and sometimes even repair them (i.e, make them report their actual capacity). Some of these tools include [h2testw](https://fightflashfraud.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/h2testw-gold-standard-in-detecting-fake-capacity-flash/), [F3](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/), and [FixFakeFlash](https://fixfakeflash.wordpress.com/).

Comment: That seems to be just exactly true.  I tried f2write a few days ago and it took 2 days ... before it crashed the computer.  So I didn't get a chance to run f3read on it.  Just now f3Probe stated that the useable size was 14.61GB.  Thanks for all this!